# Insert a new document to a MongoDB or replace exited

Tags: mongodb

Can't figure out how to create a query to MongoDB to either insert
a new document, or update it, if it exists but contains price less
than price of a new item:

```js
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

main();

async function main()
{
    const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://hello:hello@127.0.0.1:27017/admin');
    await client.connect();

    const updated_at = Date.now();
    const input = [
        {_id: 'prod1', price: 1, title: 'ball', updated_at},
        {_id: 'prod1', price: 2, title: 'umbrella', updated_at},
        {_id: 'prod1', price: 3, title: 'cactus', updated_at},
        {_id: 'prod1', price: 1, title: 'penguin', updated_at},
        {_id: 'prod1', price: 2, title: 'chair', updated_at},
        {_id: 'prod1', price: 5, title: 'map', updated_at},
        {_id: 'prod2', price: 1, title: 'mug', updated_at},
    ];

    // I can upsert a document unconditionally:
    const abc = client.db().collection('abc');
    await abc.bulkWrite(input.map(function (item) {
        return {
            replaceOne: {
                filter: {
                   _id: item._id,
                },
                replacement: item,
                upsert: true,
            },
        };
    }));

    // But, after extending condition a little bit, I got an error:
    //     E11000 duplicate key error collection: admin.abc index: _id_ dup key: { _id: "prod1" }
    await abc.bulkWrite(input.map(function (item) {
        return {
            replaceOne: {
                filter: {
                   _id: item._id,
                    price: {$lt: item.price},
                },
                replacement: item,
                upsert: true,
            },
        };
    }));

    await client.close();
}
```

Comment: This happens because on some cases the "old" document has a price which is higher or equal to the "new" document, and according to your code it should now create a new document alongside the old one. I'm not sure that this is what you want.

Comment: If there is not document with such an `_id` you want to create a new one. If there is, do you want to update it only in cases where the older price is lower or equal? what do you want to do in case of existing document with higher price than the new one?

Comment: @nimrodserok If no document with specified `_id` exists - insert it. Otherwise, replace it only if its `price` is lower than new `price`. So, if `price` of a document in db is higher - keep it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new document if it does not exists, but if it is exists then update the entire document but only if the new price is higher, you can use an update with a pipeline in your bulk. Something like:

```
bulk.find( { _id: item._id} ).upsert().updateOne(
  [{$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$cond: [
          {$gte: ["$price", item.price]},
          "$$ROOT",
          item
  ]}}}],
);
```

See How it works on the [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NM4qjuD4eV8)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not enough since other attributes should also be copied, and attributes which is in db but not in new document - should be unset.

Comment: I updated the answer according to your comment